# Extract a particular value from categorical column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

Following is the sample table which consists of transaction data of bank customers. I need to create a separate column as annual salary of customer taking the data from `txn_description` column.

```
Customer_ID txn_description Amount Type
01           POS            345    Dr
02           SALARY         2000   Cr
03           INTER BANK     148    Dr
04           SALARY         1500   Cr
05           NEFT           289    Dr
06           SALARY         1800   Cr
01           NEFT           40     Dr
02           SALARY         2000   Cr
04           POS            69     Dr
04           SALARY         1500   Cr
06           SALARY         1800   Cr
```

Note: The transaction data is of three months. So the salary is credited to a particular customer's account thrice in this table for three months.

(Dr = Debit transaction and Cr = Credit transaction)

Comment: what is the logic behind `taking annual salary of customer` from three months of data? what do you mean by this `Since the transaction data is of three months the customer ID will not be unique.`?

Comment: A customer is getting some amount credited to his account as salary. We need to calculate his annual salary based on that data....

Comment: Great. How about when we have salary data of 3 months and not one month...Check edits...

Comment: In that case, you have to filter by month and customer. i.e., the whole filtered dataframe whould have only one entry out of three months. What I suggest is, do this, `df.sort(["Customer_ID", "Date"])` and `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Customer_ID", "Date"], keep='first')`. This will have the above mentioned condition.

Comment: After sorting shall I proceed with  df[df["txn_description"]=="SALARY"]
df["Annual"] = df["Amount"]*12

Comment: yes ofcourse you have to do, but I suggest you to do this after removing duplicate, just for improving performance. drop duplicate reduces number of rows, so, if you apply `df["Annual"] = df["Amount"]*12` on reduced rows, it will improve the running time. If you feel my answer is helpful, click on grey tick mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this,

```
df= df[df["txn_description"]=="SALARY"]
df["Annual"] = df["Amount"]*12
```

O/P:

```
   Customer_ID txn_description  Amount  Annual
1            2          SALARY    2000   24000
3            4          SALARY    1500   18000
5            6          SALARY    1800   21600
```

Furthermore, If you want to apply it on original frame find this,

```
dic = df.set_index("Customer_ID")["Annual"].to_dict()
```

and apply it to actual dtaframe using `df.map(dic)`

Explanation:

1. First remove unwanted records, get only 'cr' or Salary records.
2. Now Dataframe has salary credited record of a month data of each customer. i.e., customer id and amount is one to one map.
3. multiply amount with 12 to get annual value.
4. convert customer to annual value in dic and replace into actual frame.